# R Shiny with validate: Plot only refreshes after resizing window

Tags: r, validation, resize, window, shiny

I'm trying to use validate() in Shiny, but I keep encountering an issue every time the validation command finds an error. I'm trying to plot something where occasionally some subcategory of data might not have any values (i.e. if the categories are colors, you can select "green", but sometimes the dataset will not contain any rows in category "green").

Whenever the condition I'm validating comes back as false, the error message prints correctly. However, when I then re-select a new value and update, the new plot only appears after I manually resize the window, as opposed to appearing as it normally would after I click "update".

```
colors = c("green","blue","red")
library(shiny)

ui <- fluidPage(

  tabsetPanel(
    tabPanel("Info",
             selectInput(inputId = "color",label = "color:",
                         choices = colors,
                         selected = colors[2],
                         multiple = FALSE),
             actionButton(inputId = "go",
                          label = "Update"),
             plotOutput("plot", width = "100%", height = 700,
                        brush = brushOpts(id = "plot_brush",fill = "green",clip = FALSE))

    )
  )
)

server <- function(input, output,session) {

  data = eventReactive(input$go, {
    var1 = rnorm(20,5)
    cat1 = (c(rep("red",10),rep("blue",10)))
    data = cbind.data.frame(var1,cat1)
    plotdata = data[which(data$cat1 ==isolate(input$color)),]

  }
  )

  output$plot = renderPlot({

    validate(
      need(  (isolate(input$color) %in% c("red","blue"))  , "No color of this type " )
    )

    plotdata = data()
    plot(plotdata$var1, col = isolate(input$color)) 
  })
}

shinyApp(ui = ui,server = server)
```

FYI I'm using Shiny version 0.13.1, R version 3.2.3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is that `input$color` is wrapped in `isolate` in your `need` statement. So the `need` still thinks that you have chosen the wrong color because nothing tells it to recheck `input$color`. If you add `input$go` as the first line of your `renderPlot` (just before the `validate`) I think it does what you want.

Comment: That does fix it, but I like having the isolate statement so that the colors don't change until you hit the "update" button. Any idea why the resizing of the window is what triggers the change in that case, as opposed to just the update button?

Comment: You can keep the `isolate` just add the input from the button so the plot will trigger. My guess is that when you resize, shiny has to reconstruct the plot, so it runs the `renderPlot`, and then the `validate` is reassessed.

Comment: Brilliant! Thanks, I didn't realize you could put the actionbutton inside renderplot.